# ASP MVC way to repopulate dropdown list without requerying database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, validation

**Problem**

I have a list of view models. Most of the view models have a dropdown input. When the ModelState is valid everything goes fine and I am able to handle inputting the data however when an error occurs in the form validation everything goes a mess because the dropdown menus need to be repopulated with data. This is a bit of a problem because each view model has a different dropdown list.

**Attempted Solution**

I can go thought each view model and get is corresponding domain model from the database but that doesn't seem very efficient (especially since there might be about 30 fields and each one might have a different dropdown list!).

Is there anyway to have the dropdowns persist if the form validation fails?

Comment: you have 30 dropdowns in the view ? !!!

Comment: @Shyju It might be possible. Right now its only about 5-10. Not each view model has to display a dropdown list but I am just trying to plan for the worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to have the dropdowns persist if the form validation fails?

There's nothing built-in. One possibility is to [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) the results of those database calls to avoid hitting it everytime. So you would simply have methods that either return the lists from the cache, or if not present query the database, store the resulting list to the cache and return the results. Then if a validation error occurs you will invoke those methods to repopulate your dropdownlists. It's simple and effective way, especially for dropdownlists whose values do not change often.

Comment: Ok the only problem is that right now I am populating the dropdown list in my mapping code when I go to DomainModel to ViewModel. From a design perspective is it a bad idea to populate a dropdown in AutoMapping code or should that be the controller's responsibility?

Comment: No, it's not a bad idea to populate dropdown lists in mapping code. It's the correct way to do it. It's just that when you are calling your mapping method from the controller you will pass it the cached version of the domain model that the controller retrieved.